# How to make server power settings apply even when computer is activated by WOL

Tags: networking, power-management, wake-on-lan

I have a computer with 9 hdds as a storage server in the next room for me and my family (movies and such) connected to the router. The computer is without keyboard and monitor, all works fine, but in power options I have it set to sleep after 2 hours of inactivity. When I power-on that computer normally, it really goes to sleep in 2 hours. But when I wake it up through the LAN - Wake On LAN (WOL) magic packet, it starts perfectly in 3-5 seconds but goes to sleep in a few minutes -- maybe after 3 or 5 minutes or so.

I'm sure if I attach a keyboard and touch any key, it will remain awake for 2 hours, but when I wake it up through the LAN, it goes to sleep shortly after I am not accessing it. There is 2 hours in power option, so it should go to sleep as I mentioned, but it doesn't work when I wake this computer through the LAN with WOL magic packet.

Any ideas how can I make this computer stay awake for 2 hours after I wake up it through the LAN without touching it?

Comment: Check your BIOS for sleep states. Also, check Windows for the exact sleep state S1-5 that Windows is going into when it sleeps. WOL sound only wake the machine but we've had problems with the opposite - if you "shutdown" then WOL works; if you pull the power then it doesn't. WOL is a pain. vPro is better but Intel only and needs configuring.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris, i was hoping i will find something in BIOS that i can change, but there is not so much i can do.. in Suspend type i can choose S1, S3 or Auto.. had S3, changed it to Auto but same thing.. computer went sleep within 2 minutes after i stopped copying files.. the rest options in bios are HPET (turned ON), PWRON on power fail (turned ON), Resume by LAN (turned ON - using onboard network card), Resume by PCI,PCIE,USB,PS2,RTC - turned OFF. There is nothing else i can change in BIOS. How can i check Windows sleep state that Windows is going into?i have no vPro feature

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting the default system unattended sleep timeout in the Registry. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0\DefaultPowerSchemeValues`. When you expand it there are 3 keys:

- key `381b` is for Balanced
- `8c5e` for High Performance
- `a184` for Power Saver

The default value for all is 120 seconds. I changed it to 7200 (2hrs) for both AC and DC and it works perfectly.